# Want to send mail after specific time in Java

Tags: java, servlets, multithreading

I want to send mail after specific time

Actually I want to send mail after 23 hour from the specific date

Now I am using java.util.TimerTask Thread to call that email function

Please help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of [`Timer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [`TimerTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) should suffice. The `Timer` class has a [`schedule()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29) method. Just pass the `TimerTask` and a `Date` representing today plus 23 hours along it.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
timer.schedule(new MailTask(), todayPlus23hours);
```

where the `MailTask` look like this:

```
public class MailTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        // Implement.
    }
}
```

Comment: but my specific date changes on specific time so i can't add it as hardcoded

Comment: Then just calculate it dynamically? You should really elaborate the **actual problem** in more detail. It now look more like that your problem is with calculating the date and not with executing the task.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use something like QuartZ Scheduler which will help manage scheduling and executing tasks:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/